# <Div> square shaped

Tags: html, css

```css
.products
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
}

.box
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: darksalmon;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Ola</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the paragraph to appear inside a square. The code as it is shows that the 2 divs are together. And only the content inside the paragraph appears.

This image ilustrates the format I intend:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.products
{position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
}

.box
{p
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: darksalmon;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">

    <p>Ola</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Ivan your code just makes the paragraph appear 3 times in a horizontal line floating on the left. 
And Anonymous your code just makes the paragraph appear the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
background-color: ;
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
```

Comment: Does nothing also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<p class="box">...</p>
```

removing the div wrapping your paragraph?

Comment: I would try inspecting your HTML elements and making changes to the CSS in your inspector; that way you can see any changes that you make instantly. Unfortunately, my work network is blocking imgur.com so I can't see the result that you are trying to achieve.